# HLF fabric-network fails to connect to IBP2 peer from node-red

Tags: node.js, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am currently using IBM Blockchain Platform 2.0. I am connecting to it with `fabric-network 1.4.0` and `fabric-client 1.4.0`.

When I listen for events from a simple node.js script on my machine, it works perfectly well. Here is the sample script:

```
const ccpPath = path.resolve('C:/Users/FlorianCastelain/Documents/GitHub/blockchain-code/node-red/fabric-server/config/org1/ibp2/user1/connection.json');
const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));


const walletPath = path.resolve('C:/Users/FlorianCastelain/Documents/GitHub/blockchain-code/IBP2/CHAINCODE/public-resource/profile/wallet');
const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);


const gateway = new Gateway();
const options = { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: false } };
await gateway.connect(ccp, options);

const network = await gateway.getNetwork('CHANNELNAME');

const contract = network.getContract('CCNAME');

const channel = network.getChannel();

const eventHub = channel.newChannelEventHub('IP:PORT');
let event = eventHub.registerChaincodeEvent('CCNAME', 'EVENTREGEX', (event, number, txid, status) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.payload.toString());
    console.log(number);
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
}, { startBlock: 0 });
eventHub.connect(true);
```

However, my goal is to include this code into node-red nodes (check [here](https://github.com/cazfletch/node-red-contrib-fabric).

A bit of context: currently these nodes do not handle discovery, which may be needed. The purpose of my work is to include this into these nodes.

As a consequence, I tried to insert the code above into my nodes code, which gives the following: (same code, it is just a copy/paste)

```
else if (actionType === 'event') {
  node.log('EVENT');
  const ccPath = path.resolve('C:/Users/FlorianCastelain/Documents/GitHub/blockchain-code/node-red/fabric-server/config/org1/ibp2/user1/connection.json');
  const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccPath, 'utf8'));
  const walletPath = path.resolve('C:/Users/FlorianCastelain/Documents/GitHub/blockchain-code/IBP2/CHAINCODE/public-resource/profile/wallet');
  const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);

  const gateway = new Gateway();
  const options = { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalHost: false } };
  await gateway.connect(ccp, options);
  const network = await gateway.getNetwork('CHANEL NAME');
  const channel = network.getChannel();
  const eventHub = channel.newChannelEventHub('IP:PORT');
  let event = eventHub.registerChaincodeEvent('CCNAME', 'REGEX', (event, number, txid, status) => {
  console.log(event);
    console.log(event.payload.toString());
    console.log(number);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }, { startBlock: 0 });
  eventHub.connect(true);

  // const networkInfo = await connect(identityName, node.connection.discoveryEnabled, node.connection.discoveryAsLocalhost, channelName, contractName, node);
  // const channel = networkInfo.network.getChannel();
  // await subscribeToEvent(channel, contractName, msg.payload.peerName, msg.payload.startBlock,
  //     msg.payload.endBlock, msg.payload.timeout, msg.payload.eventName, node, msg);
} else if
```

It produces the following error:

```
{ Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed

 at Object.exports.createStatusError (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\common.js:91:15)

  at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:233:26)

   at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:211:8)

  at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1306:15)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:568:42)
   at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1123:18
code: 14,   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },   details:
'Connect Failed' }
```

I checked `fabric-network` version on both "environment", it is `1.4.0`

Does anyone has a clue on what can be the difference and/or what can cause this error?

---

Edit:

When testing the package when linking it to node-red via `npm install PATH` instead of using `npm link`, I get the following error:

```
{ Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\common.js:91:15)
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:233:26)
    at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js:211:8)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1306:15)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at C:\Users\FlorianCastelain\Documents\GitHub\node-red-contrib-fabric\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1123:18
  code: 14,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'failed to connect to all addresses' }
```

---

Edit: More info from HLF logging. You can find the entire logs [here](https://gist.github.com/floriancastelain/39dc1ac5829ced4434da8b8b0c547a72)

All addresses have been changed to `ADDRESS` or `ADDRESS:PORT` (depending on what was written), except localhost addresses, for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current default (1.4.0-1.4.4) when discovery is used is for all returned ip addresses to be converted to localhost. You need to explicitly disable this. In your code I see you have tried but got the property name slightly wrong. It should be `asLocalhost` with a small `h` whereas you have used a capital `H`